# Why using renderMessage in react-native-gifted-chat removes my Avatar?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have a react native app, with `react-native-gifted-chat`. I wanted to change my `fontFamily` in all places so I changed it in the `renderComposer` and `renderMessage` props. After adding the `renderMessage` prop to my `GiftedChat` component my `Avatars` dissapeared. I tried to bring it back with the `renderAvatar`, but it does not work...

How can I have custom fonts and custom `Avatars` at the same time?

```js
<GiftedChat
    messages={messages}
    onSend={onSend}
    user={{
    _id: 1,
    avatar: USER_AVATAR,
    name: USER_ID
    }}
    
    //Custom styles
    dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD"
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    renderInputToolbar={props => customtInputToolbar(props)}
    renderSystemMessage={props => customSystemMessage(props)}
    renderSend={props => customSendButton(props)}
    renderComposer={props => customComposer(props)}
    renderMessage={props => customMessageBubble(props)}
    renderAvatar={(props) => <Avatar {...props} />}
/>

...my styles...

export const customMessageBubble = props => {
    const renderMessageText=(props)=>{
        return (
            <>
            <MessageText
                {...props}
                textStyle={{
                right:{
                    fontFamily:'QuicksandMedium'
                },
                left:{
                    fontFamily:'QuicksandMedium'
                }
                }}
            />
            </>
        )
    }

    return(
        <Bubble 
        {...props}
        renderMessageText={renderMessageText}
        />
    )
}

export const customComposer = props => {
    return(
        <Composer 
        {...props} 
        placeholder={'Aa'}
        textInputStyle={{
            fontFamily:'QuicksandMedium',
        }}
        />
    )
}
```

[image]